# How do I bring the Done button of Decimal Pad to the right side on iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, keyboard, uikeyboard

On iOS - when we use Decimal Pad as the Keyboard Type for a Text Field, the virtual keyboard displays with a Done button on the top left corner of the keyboard by default. Is there anyway to customize it to the top right side of the keyboard?

[image]

I found this code is used to display the button on the keyboard. But couldn't find any way to move it to the right side.

Thanks. :)

Comment: The Decimal Pad keyboard does not provide the Done button. That is something you need to add yourself. You need to setup the `inputAccessoryView` to put the Done button where you want it.

Comment: "when we use Decimal Pad as the Keyboard Type for a Text Field, the virtual keyboard displays with a Done button on the top left corner of the keyboard by default" No it doesn't. _You_ must be putting it there. If you can put it there you can put it on the other side, I suppose.

Comment: Hi, please check my updated question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to add a `UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace` to the toolbar *before* the Done button; this will fill up the available space and move the button to the right. Without seeing your code, it should work something like this:

```
NSMutableArray *items = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[items addObject:[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil]];
[items addObject:[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Done"
                                                    style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                                                   target:self
                                                   action:@selector(doneButtonTapped:)];];
[toolbar setItems:items];
```

Comment: Thanks mate. It works perfectly. So basically we need to add space before the button. I was looking for rightAlignment or something similar. :)